# Tool-bar icons are invisible

Tags: tool-bar

I'm having the following problem: In emacs the tool bar icons are invisible [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZKRm.png). There should be icons like `visit new file`, `save buffer` etc below the menu at the top and above the buffer. By the way, they aren't missing, I can still click them. The icons are just blank. I can even hover over them or press them, it all works.

I have no idea why this happened, nor do I know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: try `M-: (tool-bar-mode 1)`.  May be you have `(tool-bar-mode -1)` in your init file.

Comment: @DJJ that didn't do anything. By the way, they aren't missing, I can still click them. The icons are just  I can even hover over them or press them, it all works.blank.

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with you init file. Try launching emacs in quick mode without any loading any file. In the command line it's `emacs -Q`. Then loading the init files little by little to bring your emacs back.

Comment: @DJJ emacs -Q doesn't have it working either.

Comment: My suggestion is then to backup the init file and install emacs again. In my opinion it should be quicker to solve if you have no clue

Comment: @DJJ Reinstalling doesn't solve it either. I guess the problem is in a dependency. As far as I know graphical stuff is only in gtk3, so I reinstalled that too but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an outdated gtk3 theme, try the default adwaita. The latest gtk update was breaking for many existing themes, see for example https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=361066.